# Visual Studio 2012 and Web Essentials 2012 Crashing when trying to open a CSS file

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 RTM Plus updates and Web Essentials 2012 V1.7 installed on Windows Server 2012 and I get the following crash when I open a CSS file.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.ComponentLocatorWithOrdering`2.ImportMany() at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.ComponentLocatorForContentType`1.FindFirstOrderedComponent(String
>   contentTypeName) at
>   Microsoft.CSS.Editor.CssEditorDocument.InitializeTextBuffer(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer) at
>   Microsoft.CSS.Editor.CssEditorDocument.FromTextBuffer(ITextBuffer
>   textBuffer) at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.DisplayInlineTextViewCreationListener.SubjectBuffersConnected(IWpfTextView
>   textView, ConnectionReason reason, Collection`1 subjectBuffers) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.ConnectionManager.<>c_*DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b*_1()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object
>   errorSource, Action call)

I've logged in as another user instead of local admin and still I get crashes. (I have to log in as a normal user with Admin rights because some of the ide will not run in the context of the local admin for security reasons I guess).

I've uninstalled, re-installed, performed devenv / resetuser data and still it crashes.

If I uninstall the Web Essentials 2012 v1.7 (and 1.4,1.5 etc) It stops crashing. Prior to V1.4 I believe it was working ok. It may be other extensions that are in the environment clashing, like workbench tools but there is nothing added in that I can see and I've uninstalled everything I can think of.

I'd like to track down this error and understand the extensions install sequence and try and understand what it is about to do so I have some clue of anything that could affect it.

#### Previous Entry

> "Begin package load [Visual Studio CSS Editing Package]
>   {A764E895-518D-11D2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}  VisualStudio 2012/11/12
>   12:10:02.504  484  Loading UI library
>             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages*\CSSPkgUI.dll {A764E895-518D-11D2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}  VisualStudio 2012/11/12
>   12:10:02.504  485  End package load [Visual Studio CSS Editing
>   Package] {A764E895-518D-11D2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}  VisualStudio
>   2012/11/12 12:10:02.505 "

From what I can see the Microsoft web editor is trying to hand over the contents of the edit buffer to Web Essentials Editor extension and blows up.

#### EventLog

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.NullReferenceException Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.ComponentLocatorWithOrdering`2[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ImportMany()    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Editor.ComponentLocatorForContentType`1[[System._*Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].FindFirstOrderedComponent(System.String)
>   at
>   Microsoft.CSS.Editor.CssEditorDocument.InitializeTextBuffer(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBuffer)
>   at
>   Microsoft.CSS.Editor.CssEditorDocument.FromTextBuffer(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBuffer)
>   at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.HighlightWordTagger.EnsureInitialized()
>   at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.HighlightWordTagger.UpdateAtCaretPosition(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.CaretPosition)
>   at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.HighlightWordTagger+<>c*_DisplayClass3.b__2()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

I notice that it mentions `highlightword` tagger. Is that a clue? (or just the first point of call?), I have no colour syntax highlighting in a html file either.

I also had the same crash multiple times on a separate windows 8 laptop and one day the error just vanished after I sat uninstalling and bashing it to death, I tried so many disable, enable, round trips its difficult to think what might have fixed it.

Are there any other logs I can trace this with?

Comment: Code formatting and Blockquote formatting would help this post greatly.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in the latest nightly build. You can grab it here: http://madskristensen.net/custom/webessentials2012.vsix?v=1.7.4

Installing the nightly will not affect any future updates to be installed automatically through VS.

Comment: Thanks Mads, Sadly it didn't help. I tried a repair prior too. I'm perplexed as to where the colour syntax higlighting went in html and css files. I'll try a complete uninstall but it feels like the environment is cluttered with something.

Comment: Hi Mads, I performed an uninstall, reboot, reinstall, devenve /resetuserdata, then created a new web store app and got... "The 'EditorExtensionsPackage' package did not load correctly. That turned out to be the local extensions cache remembered the previous install. I installed the Web Essentials 2012 v1.7 and I still got the same error. See below

Comment: Microsoft.CSS.Editor.CssEditorDocument.FromTextBuffer(ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.DisplayInlineTextViewCreationListener.SubjectBuffersConnected(IWpfTextView textView, ConnectionReason reason, Collection`1 subjectBuffers)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.ConnectionManager.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)</description>
  </entry></activity>

Comment: Just tried the web platform installer and got the web tooling 1.1. This environment was contaminated with VS2012 Express since the installer decided that VS 2012 editions could be splatted all over each other rather than detect a higher edition was already installed. There is seemingly no way to sanitise the entire system, as usual, so we are left facing a complete system rebuild but I'll try to avoid that.

Comment: bahh humbug, I'm going to uninstall again and find the package caches, delete them and this time run the install from the ISO. (Hoping it doesn't get any updates to VS2012).

Comment: I decided not to tear in and delete the package cache but before the iso I just deleted two sets of VS2012 (11 and 11_config) registry keys. But got the same error as usual.

Comment: It's odd that even if I uninstall the Web Essentials extension I can't get any colour syntax back to html or css. It's like an underlying editor is bust.

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled from DVD and after deleting the packages cache too and watched it reaquire and still it crashes. Clearly something is corrupt with the installation and clearly the uninstall doesn't clean up correctly either. After a complete trashing (so I thought) it still reinstalled and knew of the Web Essentials being installed. Now I am going to hunt down a restore point :)

Comment: excellent, no system restore point in windows server 2012, just great, though I thought I remember seeing it set one, must have been dreaming.

Comment: ripped out VS 2012 and package cache and as many registry entries that looked related to vs11, now installing again, sigh...

Comment: sigh, it blew up straight away

Comment: Oh well, I just tried Web Essentials V1.8 and got the same crash. I guess Visual Studio 2012 has trashed my server. Time to waste another couple of days rebuilding it. It's disgraceful of MS not to provide a tool to clean out an application like VS2012 properly. Mads thanks for trying to help, if there is anything you think I can trace or debug let me know... Off to sulk.

Comment: I have this same issue with VS 2013.  Uninstalling WE was the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I did indeed rebuild my machine and of course I've never seen the error again. I did however choose to rebuild as Windows 8 PC instead of Windows 2012 Server as my dev machine.